# Finding adjoint of a function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $Ax=\langle a,x\rangle$ for all $a\neq 0\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Compute for the adjoint of $A$.

Here's my solution:
I need to show that
$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$ where the $A^*$ is my adjoint. I have,

$\langle Ax,y\rangle =\langle\langle a,x\rangle ,y\rangle =\langle a,x\rangle y =\langle x,a\rangle y$

And now I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: How do you define an inner product  $\langle c,x\rangle$, where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Um. Is that possible? Or I dunno if this is right $c\sum_ix_i$?

Comment: What is your definition of adjoint (or transpose)?

Comment: The usual adjoint operator. $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$

Comment: @REIVAX obviously that definition does not make sense in this context. Your professor should have told you what it means in this context. Has he/she defined the transpose of a linear map?

Comment: Um. Of course it doesn't make sense in that context. What I'm trying to say is that I'm looking for that $A^*$ that would be the adjoint of $A$. It could be anything actually such as $A^T,A^TA$.

Comment: I'll post an answer tomorrow. In the meantime use "@username" to notify "username" of your message

Comment: @lcv I already got an answer. I just don't know if this is right. $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,ay\rangle=\langle x,A^*y\rangle$. Hence $A^*y=ay$.